# Oracle Extract Column in Main query from Exists clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get value of `'send_followup_ind'` in main query from Oracle EXISTS clause. Currently getting some error while running below query. Can someone help me on this ?

Query:

```
SELECT p.patient_id as patient_id, phs.send_followup_ind
FROM patient P, call c
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT COALESCE(sfgc.send_followup_ind, ffgc.send_followup_ind) AS send_followup_ind
                FROM FACILITY_GRP_CONFIG ffgc, STUDY_FACILITY_GRP_CONFIG sfgc
                WHERE ffgc.facility_grp_id = sfgc.facility_grp_id(+)
                AND sfgc.study_id = P.study_id ) AS phs
    AND p.patient_id = c.patient_id
    AND P.release_date > to_date('01-01-2020', 'MM-DD-YYYY');
```

Comment: Why are you choosing to use archaic join syntax instead of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: How about telling us what the error is?

Comment: Invalid SQL Statement after phs.send_followup_ind

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not possible to get the value from "exists" subquery. You need to use inner join intead of exists to be able to retrieve the data from joined tables.